# SPM12 debugging on Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, matlab-spm

I have a problem using SPM on Matlab. I have an `m-file` that I need to debug and I have not written. 
This code is old and probably the error is hopefully given by the difference in syntax of the newer versions. 
The error pops out using this function `spm_get_files`, originally present in the code. When changing this function to `spm_get` (I found that these two functions are supposedly equivalent) I get the following error:

```
Error using spm_get (line 1726)
Illegal Action string
Error in suj6 (line 46)
Fr3 = spm_get('/home/***/folder','a3*093.img');
```

where `'/home/***/folder','a3*093.img'` is the directory of the input files I want to analyze. These are fMRI scans.

My Matlab version is 9(R2016a) and the SPM is SPM12. (The code is old and was originally written in SPM99)

Anyone can help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`spm_get_files` is basically just this one line of code:

```
varargout = {spm_get('Files',varargin{:})};
```

Clearly if you would like to switch back to using spm_get, you need to explicitly add 'Files' as the first argument.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what my mistake in the code is.
if I use `spm_get_files('/home/***/folder','a3*093.img')` this gives me an error and it does not upload the files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your original post, you posted the error message you get when "changing this function to `spm_get`". If you also get error message when you use `spm_get_files`, please post what the error message is.